# C# Destroying the effects of a class

Tags: c#

I have a public class Puzzle that creates a puzzle of buttons (a 2d array of buttons) and places them in Form1 of my Windows Form Application(It sets Form1 as their Parent). when I call a function to remove all these buttons except for the reset_button, it will delete only half of them. I have to call this method n times in order to get all these buttons deleted, where n x n = the number of buttons my puzzle has.

```
public void Remove(Form g)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
            foreach (Button b in g.Controls)
            {
                if (b.Name!="btn_reset") b.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

in the Form1 class puzzle is a new instance of the class Puzzle, and Remove is a public method within the class Puzzle

```
btn_reset.MouseClick += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                puzzle.Remove(this);
                //puzzle=new Puzzle(n,this);
            };
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: why do you have a double nested for loop in your Remove function?

Comment: @Nzall Because I needed to call the foreach loop n times in order to dispose of ALL the buttons. It would dispose only half of them each time otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not removing the buttons only disposing them. I would suggest this code:

```
public void Remove(Form g)
{
    var toRemove = g.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name != "btn_reset").ToList();
    foreach(Button b in toRemove)
    {
        g.Controls.Remove(b);
    }
}
```

Please note:

- You have to create a new List of the controls (`toRemove` in the example) because you cannot directly iterate over `Controls` and remove items from this list.
- You have to add `using System.Linq;`

**UPDATE**:
As stated by other users, dispose also removes controls from its parent. So the actual problem was not the call to `Dispose` but the way you used the iterator .So you could also use this code

```
public void Remove(Form g)
{
    var toRemove = g.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name != "btn_reset").ToList();
    foreach(Button b in toRemove)
    {
        b.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: after removing each b from `g.Controls`, shouldn't you call also `b.Dispose()`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with how `foreach` and enumerables work.

When you start iterating over the `ControlCollection`, an iterator object is created. This object keeps track of the current index in the collection. But now you dispose the first control - what happens? The first control in the collection is removed. But the iterator doesn't know - it just increments the current index, and skips the control right after the one that was removed.

The solution is either to create a copy of the control collection (e.g. `g.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name != "btn_reset").ToList()`), or to use a simple loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < g.Controls.Count; i++)
{
  if (g.Controls[i].Name == "btn_reset") continue;

  g.Controls[i].Dispose();
  i--;
}
```

Enumerables are only safe when you do no side-effects - and modifying the collection being enumerated is definitely a side-effect. In more recent collections (like `List<>`), iterating a collection that is being modified throws an exception - `ControlCollection` is just too old for that.